# Are there grammatical terms that clearly distinguish between words that join clauses and those that join words in a list?

Tags: meaning, grammar, terminology

The grammatical term *conjunction* is used to identify words that join things together in some kind of relation, but joining clauses is very different than joining words in a list. Are there any terms that make this distinction clear?

> Tom ***and*** Judy will walk the dog.
>
> You choice is between chocolate ***or*** vanilla.

In these sentences the words *and* and *or* are just joining words in a list, within the same clause.

The term *conjunction* is used to identify words that join things together in some kind of relation, but joining clauses is very different than joining words in a list.

> Tom will walk the dog in the morning ***and*** Judy will walk the dog
>   tonight.
>
> Give me liberty ***or*** give me death.

Comment: Either way, don't you think that Question belongs in English Language Learners?

Comment: Please support your assertion that these are ***very different***

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are [coordinating conjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Coordinating_conjunctions), a term which applies to these words whether they're uniting items in a list or independent clauses in a sentence.

I am unaware of any term that clearly distinguishes coordinating conjunctions that function on the lexical, phrasal, and clausal level. If I had to make the distinction, I might say that your first examples are coordinating conjunctions that connect words, and your second examples are coordinating conjunctions that connect clauses.